# mean of the function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

The mean of any function $u(x,y)$ alond the $x$-axis is
\begin{equation}
\bar u(y) = \int_0^1 u(x,y) \, dx.
\end{equation}
If we know the value of $\bar u(y)$ at $x=0$ and $\bar u(y)$ at $x=1$ and they are equal. How can we express the function $\bar u(y)$? Or the value of $\bar u(y)$ same at any point of the $x$-axis with the boundary values?

Comment: $\overline{u}$ here is a value, not a function. So, $\overline{u}$(0) and $\overline{u}$(1) don't really make sense.

Comment: I don't get it. $\bar u$ is a constant, not a function.

Comment: If you mean that we know $u(0)$ and $u(1)$ (instead of $\bar{u}$), then I can say that the end points tell nothing about the mean value. Who knows, $u$ could jump into very high or very low numbers in between $0$ and $1$, and the mean value would follow that.

Comment: What does the value of $\overline{u}(y)$ at $x=0$ mean?  $\overline{u}$ is a function of $y$, not $x$.  In fact, $x$ is integrated out, so this statement is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

> If we know the value of $\bar u(0)$ and $\bar u(1)$, how can we express the function $\bar u$?

You may mean (pun not intended!) $u(0)$ and $u(1)$ since the function is $u$ and $\bar u$ is the mean, a number.

Well: you don't need $u(0)$ and $u(1)$ but $U(0)$ and $U(1)$ where $U$ is an anti-derivative (or 'primitive function', so satisfying $U' = u$) of $u$ since, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, you can find this $\bar u$ as follows (addition in blue):

> The mean of any function $u$ alond the $x$-axis is
>   \begin{equation}
> \bar u = \int_0^1 u \, dx = \color{blue}{U(1)-U(0)}
> \end{equation}

Note that this is fine for the mean on $[0,1]$ (because its length is $1$), but to get the mean on an arbitrary interval $[a,b]$, you would need to divide by $b-a$, the length of the interval.